# on unauthorised request default redirection is happening in ajax call .net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have a action method decorated with `[CustomAuthorize]` attribute. this method i'm calling from `javascript`. Basically if user is authenticated then only this method should execute. If not user should redirect to custom error page.

```
[CustomAuthorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostData(Model model)
{

}
```

In the script in `ajaxerror` block if status code is 401, i'm redirecting to custom error page.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 401)
        window.location = "/error/customerror";
    else if (xhr.status == 403)
        alert("You have no enough permissions to request this resource.");
});
```

And i have implimented the custom authorize attribute and overloaded the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method as follows.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
       var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    var response = httpContext.Response;
    var user = httpContext.User;

    if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        else
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

        response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        response.End();
    }

    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);        }
}
```

Problem is, `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method is not being called(after authentication timeout). I have put up the break point and control is not at all coming to this method.

In the developer tool's network tab i can see 302 when i called `/PostData` method and redirection is happening to login page(actually redirection will not happen, in the response i'm getting login page's html).

[image: This is a similar request]

Any one now this issue. Please help me. I have spent more than a day on this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have a typo here `public ActionResult PostDaata(Model model)`? is the action `/PostData` or `/PostDaata`? Looks like an extra 'a' in the action definition.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently and this is how I solved it:

In your custom attribute to handle the unauthorized ajax post you should throw something else instead of the 401.  I've done something similar to present a relogin model but the built in 401 seems to be very difficult to override.

This works better anyway so you can redirect to real login on regular posts and not muddle the behavior between ajax vs hard post...   the 302 is a successful redirect or request to redirect to the browser from what I understand (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) so the 401 behavior from your web.config or server settings is still happening.

I throw a 306 instead (which is meaningless as far as i know). This is how mine is wired up:

[AjaxAuthorize] in my controllers:

```
 public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
 {
     protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
     {
         if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) filterContext.HttpContext.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] = true;
         base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
     }
 }
```

then in Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (Context.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] is bool)
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 306;
            Context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Problem is control is not coming to HandleUnauthorizedRequest method.

Comment: I know, i had the same problem throwing the 401 because you are winding up in the default handler for the 401. Also, you may want to check that you are registering the filters in the Application_Start(): FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

Comment: Any luck with this?  If you aren't hitting the filter I'm guessing it's the filters aren't registered properly... do you have any other filters you are using?other than that one?